# Is there a way to keep first row always the same when we are creating a table with reportlab?

Tags: python-3.6, reportlab

I am creating a table with reportlab library at python3. I want to keep the first row between pages as a header, is there a easy way to do it? I am using the open source version from the library and I am usually using subclass to override function then using them. I don't know if it is working on the same way. Does anyone had a similar problem?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That may help you:

```py
myTable = Table(data, repeatRows=1)

# From documentation:

Table(data, colWidths=None, rowHeights=None, style=None, splitByRow=1,repeatRows=0, repeatCols=0, rowSplitRange=None, spaceBefore=None,spaceAfter=None)
```

Comment: @JavierMonrabalMateo No problem :) Please mark the answer as accepted, so other can see that this question is solved.

Comment: There should be a mark sign under the upvote and downvote signs.